# Node.js Express App on Heroku Won't Connect to MongoLab Database using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, mongoose

I am trying to get my node.js express app to connect to a MongoLab database on Heroku using Mongoose. I have used `app.configure` to set my database URI to my MongoLab URI on `production`, and as you can see in the Heroku Logs it is definitely setting `dbURI` to the MongoLab URI. I have definitely set my `NODE_ENV` to `production`. What is my issue?

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , dbURI = 'localhost';
var app = express();

app.configure('production', function () {
    console.log("production!");
    dbURI = 'mongodb://brad.ross.35:Brad1234@ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/heroku_app6861425';
    console.log(dbURI);
});

mongoose.connect(dbURI, 'test');
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

app.configure(function () {
    //app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index');
});

app.post('/result', function(request, response) {
    var post = new Post({body: request.body.text});
    post.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error!");
        } else {
            console.log("saved!");
        }
    });

    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("found!");
            console.log(posts);
            response.render('result', {posts: posts});
        } else {
            console.log("error!");
            response.render('result', {posts: []});
        }
    });
});

app.get('/result', function (request, response) {
    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("found!");
            console.log(posts);
            response.render('result', {posts: posts});
        } else {
            console.log("error!");
            response.render('result', {posts: []});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

**Heroku Logs**:

```
2012-08-21T16:52:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-21T16:52:22+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-21T16:52:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2012-08-21T16:52:24+00:00 app[web.1]: production!
2012-08-21T16:52:24+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb://brad.ross.35:PASSWORD@ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/heroku_app6861425
2012-08-21T16:52:24+00:00 app[web.1]: connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/heroku_app6861425:27017]]
2012-08-21T16:52:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Please include the code in your post, not just links.

Comment: I get the same error when connecting over command line... `mongo -u brad.ross.35 -p Brad1234 ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/heroku_app6861425
` but maybe your password isn't really that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I'm getting this error: "Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'" I've tried a lot and haven't gotten this to work. I'm working with mongolabs support now. Have you contacted them?

Answer (score 3):

When passing a URI there is no need to pass the database name separately (which confuses mongoose).

Just do

```
var uri = 'mongodb://brad.ross.35:Brad1234@ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/heroku_app6861425'
mongoose.connect(uri)
```

to use the test db, change your uri:

```
var uri = 'mongodb://brad.ross.35:Brad1234@ds031347.mongolab.com:31347/test'
```

Comment: It goes through, but when I try to go to the /result page it just gives me an "internal server error" and logs this: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-08-22T00:27:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-08-22T00:27:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Mongoose but when I had connection problems with MongoLab in the past it was due to a race condition caused by connecting to the db and client code which assumes the connect. 
Typically the solution is to bind to the `open` event or provide a callback which is invoked by the underlying driver before resuming the start up that requires a connection.
This is what I do with `Mongoskin` and I never have an issue.

hth
mike

Comment: I don't quite understand. You mean to have a callback that executes before the rest of the app continues? Isn't that not really possible in Node? Can you be a little bit more specific and add an example maybe?

Comment: You mean nest everything else inside a callback on the `mongoose.connect` function?

Comment: Hi Brad. I had a look at mongoose docs and it fires an `open` event on the connection you receive. So just like you are binding to the 'error' event in your code you can bind to the 'open' event. Wrap your init code in a function and pass that into your `open` callback. //app.js

var startApp = function() {
  app.configure(...)
  // other init tasks
}

mongoose.connection.on 'open', startApp

Comment: I tried doing so, and it seemed to work, but I still got an `Internal Server Error` when connecting to the `/result` page...

Comment: Can you show how you are applying your init code to the 'open' event? I edited my earlier answer to this too.

Comment: Due to the restrictive character limit, here it is: http://d.pr/f/He8V. One thing to note is check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575664/node-js-connecting-to-mongodb-using-mongohq-on-heroku. I think it is some kind of router issue. Also, I think I messed up with my database. I am trying to connect to my old one that I deleted, but I should try to connect to the new one.

Comment: You might want to try binding to the `open` event like I suggested. It isn't clear from the mongoose docs whether the callback is supported like you are doing in your app.js or whether the arguments are correct. Like I said, though, I am not a mongoose guy.

Comment: bind as in... callback on the open event? I am kind of new to node.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Nodejs uses 'emit/on' for event publication/subscriptions. Other libs use 'bind/trigger' and the list goes on... 
So you can:
    mongoose.connect myUrl; 
    mongoose.connection.on 'open', initAppFn

Comment: Ok. So I did that, and it connected at first, but then it ended the process with `process ended with status 1`. I could still run requests, but it wouldn't connect to the database